# Delete corrupted folder in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, file-management, file-corruption

Whenever I try to delete this folder, the progress bar completes without any prompt but the folder is still there with it's subfolder. I tried to go into folder, but it seems after some time the path repeats itself again, i.e the path looks like /src/out/build/x64-Debug (default)/src/out/build/x64-Debug (default)/..., after going deep enough in subfolders explorer just crashes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please refer to the following article and use CMD to delete the folder:https://www.instructables.com/Deleting-an-Undeletable-Folder/

Comment: Yeah I have tried all those commands and none of them worked, they didn't prompt any error message either.

Comment: Have you restarted the the PC? See if it is still there, if it is run a chkdsk on the drive.

Answer (score 0):

It could be filesystem corruption or a symbolic link (symlink) to itself.

Symlinks are similar to shortcuts, except shortcuts will actually change the path to target directory, while symlinks will appear to work like a regular directory while displaying contents of another one. When a symlink points to its parent, entering it will append to the path but you'll be seeing the same folder contents again and again.

0. Start by making sure your backups are working and up to date. Filesystem problems can sometimes get worse when you're fixing them.
1. Start a *Command Line* with administrator privileges:

   - Press <kbd>Win</kbd>
   - Type `cmd`
   - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
   - Confirm UAC window when it appears.
2. You should see a black window with white letters. Now make sure the filesystem is not corrupted and fix it if necessary:

   - Type `chkdsk /f C:` (adjust drive letter)
   - Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   - If it's the system drive (ie. usually `C:`) the program will tel you that it can't work on that drive while the system is running and you have to reboot. Confirm by typing `Y`  <kbd>Enter</kbd> and reboot. Non-system drives should get scanned without reboots.
   - Wait... This can take less than a minute on small, fast drives, but larger and slower drives can take even an hour to scan and fix.
3. If the folder is gone, that's it!
4. If the folder is still there, try to delete it.

   - Get the path of the parent of problematic directory. Eg. if `C:\foo\magic` is recursive and goes like `C:\foo\magic\magic\magic\...` then the parent is `C:\foo`.
   - Change the directory to that path: `cd /d C:\foo` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   - Delete the culprit with a command: `rmdir magic` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Followed everything you said the Folder is still can't be deleted.